# How to differenct colors for fa fa and text using css

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have separate colors for `fa-search` and text with this html using css?

```
<a href="http://4309.co.uk/logos/"><div class="logos1"><i class="fa fa-search"><span class="padding">logos</span></i></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your request - the title of your post indicates that you want the same colors for the icon and text - but the question requests different colors.

Fa icons are colored via the color css property so you can set a given color for them. Note that the FA icons are added as ::before pseudo elements - so can be styled directly or via inherited colors.

Also - although you can have content within the i that houses the icon - it is more common to treat that as a separate element and close the `<i>` before adding the other content in the span.

EDIT: in response to the comment - I have altered the code so that the a has the logos class - so that you can directly target this and not other a elements.

```css
a.logos1 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: blue;
}

a .fa {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

 <a href="http://4309.co.uk/logos/" class="logos1">
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
   <span class="padding">logos</span>
 </a>
```

Comment: Thanks. But won't using a change all my link colors? I just want to target specific ones.

Comment: I have altered the code so that the a has the logos1 class - so that you can directly target this and not other a elements. Also note that the icon will recieve the a's color via inheritabnce - so you need to set the a color and then the .fa color to get it different.